# creating a cd-rom-area on a USB flash drive

Tags: python, usb-flash-drive, cd-rom

How to create a cd-rom-area on a USB flash drive using python? I tried to find information, and I know that there are a large number of controllers and for all there are utilities. Suppose I would like to write a program for at least one controller in python, is it possible to do this, and how should it work?

Comment: What do you mean by a cd-rom area?

Comment: How can I create an emulated CD-ROM on a flash usb